# oracle deadlock timeout configuration

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, deadlock

I have following query:

```
select col from tbl where id in (....) for update
```

so this query selects some rows from table and locks them.

Some of these rows were locked by other client (`Sql Developer` if that matters), so this query blocked waiting for sql developer to release locked rows.

After some time (about 2 hours) session which was executing first query got `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence exception`. I checked trace files and oracle treated this situation as a deadlock.

In trace file I found following

```
DUMP LOCAL BLOCKER: initiate state dump for TIMEOUT
```

So that seems that there is some timeout for locks after which they are considered deadlocked. Can I configure it?

**Trace file**

```
*** 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
*** SESSION ID:(971.57585) 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
*** CLIENT ID:() 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
*** SERVICE NAME:(asd) 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
*** MODULE NAME:(JDBC Thin Client) 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
*** ACTION NAME:() 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204

DUMP LOCAL BLOCKER/HOLDER: block level 5 res [0x60004][0x2729b9],[TX][ext 0x2,0x0]
----------resource 0x85e8435c0----------------------
resname       : [0x60004][0x2729b9],[TX][ext 0x2,0x0]
hash mask     : x3
Local inst    : 2
dir_inst      : 2
master_inst   : 2
hv idx        : 17
hv last r.inc : 54
current inc   : 54
hv status     : 0
hv master     : 0
open options  : dd
grant_bits    : KJUSERNL KJUSEREX
grant mode    : KJUSERNL  KJUSERCR  KJUSERCW  KJUSERPR  KJUSERPW  KJUSEREX
count         : 1         0         0         0         0         1
val_state     : KJUSERVS_NOVALUE
valblk        : 0x2000483508000000b01e483508000000  H5H5
access_inst   : 2
vbreq_state   : 0
state         : x0
resp          : 0x85e8435c0
On Scan_q?    : N
Total accesses: 3589
Imm.  accesses: 3151
Granted_locks : 1
Cvting_locks  : 1
value_block:  20 00 48 35 08 00 00 00 b0 1e 48 35 08 00 00 00
GRANTED_Q :
lp 0x853b8d380 gl KJUSEREX rp 0x85e8435c0 [0x60004][0x2729b9],[TX][ext 0x2,0x0]
  master 2 gl owner 0x85d645fc8 possible pid 17202 xid 45000-0002-000019AC bast 0 rseq 46 mseq 0 history 0x14951495
  open opt KJUSERDEADLOCK
CONVERT_Q:
lp 0x853b8d8f0 gl KJUSERNL rl KJUSEREX rp 0x85e8435c0 [0x60004][0x2729b9],[TX][ext 0x2,0x0]
  master 2 gl owner 0x85d63d0e8 possible pid 17571 xid 65000-0002-00001383 bast 0 rseq 46 mseq 0 history 0x1495149a
  convert opt KJUSERGETVALUE
----------enqueue 0x853b8d380------------------------
lock version     : 987233
Owner inst       : 2
grant_level      : KJUSEREX
req_level        : KJUSEREX
bast_level       : KJUSERNL
notify_func      : (nil)
resp             : 0x85e8435c0
procp            : 0x8523993e8
pid              : 17571
proc version     : 281
oprocp           : (nil)
opid             : 17571
group lock owner : 0x85d645fc8
possible pid     : 17202
xid              : 45000-0002-000019AC
dd_time          : 0.0 secs
dd_count         : 0
timeout          : 0.0 secs
On_timer_q?      : N
On_dd_q?         : N
lock_state       : GRANTED
ast_flag         : 0x0
Open Options     : KJUSERDEADLOCK
Convert options  : KJUSERNOQUEUE KJUSERNODEADLOCKWAIT
History          : 0x14951495
Msg_Seq          : 0x0
res_seq          : 46
valblk           : 0x68f4c180ff7f00000100000000000000 h
user session for deadlock lock 0x853b8d380
  sid: 965 ser: 10351 audsid: 13432555 user: 500/asd
    flags: (0x8100045) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
    flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
  pid: 69 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 17202
    image: oracle@asd
  client details:
    O/S info: user: jboss, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: asd.asd.com program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:
  <sql query omitted>
DUMP LOCAL BLOCKER: initiate state dump for TIMEOUT
  possible owner[69.17202] on resource TX-00060004-002729B9

*** 2013-09-06 15:32:07.204
Submitting asynchronized dump request [28]. summary=[ges process stack dump (kjdglblkrdm1)].
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing anything that would indicate that Oracle treated the situation as a deadlock.  If Oracle found there was a deadlock, it would have raised an ORA-00060 error and produced a deadlock trace file.

By default, Oracle will allow simple blocking locks to block forever without terminating either the blocker or the waiter.  You can, however, control how long you want to wait by making use of the `WAIT` clause.  For example

```
select col 
  from tbl 
 where id in (....) 
   for update wait 30
```

specifies that you want to wait up to 30 seconds for the rows to be locked.  If the rows remain locked after that, you'll get an ORA-30006 error "resource busy; acquire with WAIT timeout expired".

My guess is that the behavior you are seeing indicates that your DBA has used [Oracle Resource Manager to configure a resource plan that kills idle blockers after a specified length of time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/dbrm.htm#sthref3381).  You could talk to the DBA about changing that plan but that is generally more complicated and more difficult to fine-tune if you find that you want different queries and different applications to have different timeouts.

Comment: just updated query with trace file contents in case that could give any additional information

Comment: Checked `DBA_RSRC_PLAN_DIRECTIVES` there `MAX_IDLE_BLOCKER_TIME` and `MAX_IDLE_TIME` are all null